# Expanded Widget got exception(Each child must be laid out exactly once)?

Tags: flutter

I have implemented app to read captured image text using Firebase ML kit,In my screen I have display the captured image and place a button bellow the image to read the image and display extract text below the button, but when I have click the button I got following exception,

"Each child must be laid out exactly once",

I have used Huawei GR5 Mini to test the app,

My code is,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Read PDF',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.lightBlue),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  child: Image.file(File(widget.imageRoute), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: () async {
                pickImage();
              },
              child: Text(
                "Read".toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Center(
            child: text == ''
                ? Text('Text will display here')
                : Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: SelectableText(
                          text,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use expended in center widget. You can use like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Read PDF',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.lightBlue),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0, bottom: 20.0),
                child: Image.network("https://i1.wp.com/www.muratoner.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/flutterlogo.png?fit=800%2C800&ssl=1", fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              onPressed: () async {
                text = "Response text";
                setState(() {

                });
//                pickImage();
              },
              child: Text(
                "Read".toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          text == ''
              ? Text('Text will display here',textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
              : Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: SelectableText(
                  text,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the same issue, although the above solution is correct but it seems to fail sometimes.
try this command in terminal in android studio.

```
1.   flutter clean
2.   flutter run
```